# Use purrr to run multiple regression models with changing outcomes and then extract residuals

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to run some regression models with different `y` (so the independent variables stay the same for all the models), and then extract the residuals from each of these models and add them to the original data set.

I will use `diamonds` to show what I came up with:

```
# In my example, the models are: x or y or z = carat + cut + color + clarity + price

dependent = c("x", "y", "z")

model = function(y, dataset) {
 a = map(
   setNames(y, y), ~ glm(reformulate(termlabels = c("carat", "cut", "color", "clarity", "price"),
                                     response = y),
                         family = gaussian(link = "identity"),
                         data = dataset
   )) 
 
 resids = map_dfr(a, residuals)
 
 df = bind_cols(dataset, resids)

 print(df)

}

model(y = dependent, dataset = diamonds)
```

But this code doesn't work. I would also like to have sensible names for the residuals that are added as new columns, otherwise it is difficult to differentiate the residuals when the number of models is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### generate example data

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(101)
dd <- diamonds
dependent <- c("x", "y", "z")
for (d in dependent) {
  dd[[d]] <- rnorm(nrow(diamonds))
}
```

### process

```r
library(broom)
res <- (dependent
  ## set names so .id = argument works downstream
  %>% setNames(dependent)
  ## construct list of formulas
  %>% map(reformulate, termlabels = c("carat", "cut", "color", "clarity", "price"))
  ## fit glmes
  %>% map(glm, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), dd,
          na.action = na.exclude)
  ## compute resids (add observation number) and collapse to tibble
  %>% map_dfr(~tibble(.obs=seq(nrow(dd)), .resid = residuals(.)), .id = "response")
  ## widen data → residuals from each response variable as a column
  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "response", values_from = ".resid", 
                  names_prefix ="res_")
  %>% select(-.obs)
)
## combine with original data
res2 <- bind_cols(dd, res)
```

Notes:

- it's not obvious to me why you're using `glm(., family = gaussian(link = "identity))` here, unless it's as a placeholder to something more complicated you're doing with your real data. (If this is your actual model then using `lm()` will be simpler and faster.)
- adding `na.action = na.exclude` to the `[g]lm()` call will include `NA` values in the predictions, residuals, etc., which will help your residuals line up better with the original data.

Comment: It worked and thank you, Ben! Some follow-up questions: (1) SetNames works in combination with ".id = response" in the map_dfr step, and without SetNames, ".id = response" wouldn't work, correct? (2) Why map_dfr(~tibble)? I thought by using map_dfr one is specifying the output as a dataframe/tibble. (3) I didn't understand the dots in ".obs" and ".resid", so I removed the dots and the code still worked. Is this just a habbit of yours to name variables starting with a dot?

Comment: When I modify the to fit my real data, however, there are missing values in my real data so I am getting an error message saying: Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes. * Size 57: Existing data. * Size 55: Column `.resid`. ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

Comment: (1) yes. (2) `map_dfr` is to combine the results into a tibble (which is what I though you wanted) (3) including the dots in the variable names is a standard trick to minimize the chances that the new variables will clash with existing variable names in the original df.

Comment: (4) see edit with `na.exclude` ...